# How to Avoid Self Referrals in Universal Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I'm getting a lot of referral traffic listed with my own domain name in my Google Analytics tracking reports.  I'm running the same Universal Analytics tracking code on multiple subdomains for the same domain.

The tracking code (with placeholders for the Analytics account and domain name) is like this (for all the subdomains, including the www one):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
              i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                  (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
              }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
              m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
          })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

          ga('create', 'UA-1111111-1', {
              cookieDomain: 'domain.com',
              legacyCookieDomain: 'domain.com'
          });
          ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
```

The traffic is getting listed in the report as:
domain.com / referral

Am I doing something wrong that would result in the referral tracking I'm receiving?

Comment: Have you added your domains into the Referral Exclusion list?

Comment: I took a look and it turns out that I've set the following as the referral exclusions for this property:
subdomain1.domain.com
subdomain2.domain.com

I am not listing domain.com or www.domain.com in this list. Should I be? Along this train of though, am I better off just excluding domain.com (rather than each individual sub-domain) to exclude all sub-domains? (as, I don' think I have the need, in this particular property, to be concerned with tracking traffic between the sub-domains).

Comment: I haven't conclusively determined what actually works for the list so to be safe I would add domain.com and also subdomain.domain.com. I suspect that just domain.com would suffice though.